# Is this circuit measuring the electrical field?

Tags: rf, detector, field

I have found the following circuit on the web (https://electroclinica.org/2018/03/23/fabricacion-de-un-sencillo-medidor-de-campo-de-rf-diy/)

[image]

which claims to be an "RF field" detector/meter/measurer. I have never heard of an "RF" field so I assume this person is refering to the electrical field component of electromagnetic fields which compose typical RF signals. Would that be correct? The author mentions that he has tested the device with frequencies in the 1,8MHz to 30MHz range. What physical phenomenon is the circuit measuring exactly, and which role does each component play in the circuit?

Thanks

Comment: It's very like an AM crystal radio receiver but using regular diodes. (OA91 seems to trigger a distant memory that it might be a germanium type for lower forward voltage.)

Comment: @Transistor yes, those are germanium diodes. Could you please ellaborate a bit on the purpose of the circuit? Why does the original author use it to detect "RF Leakage" like he says in the website I linked? I'm specially interested in knowing what physical phenomenom are involved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't measure electric field. It show what the 2 diode rectifier happens to rectify to the sub-milliampere galvanometer. The size and the connection wire length of the galvanometer also affects the result and also how big is the person who keeps the meter in his hands. Someone is planned to have to hold it because there's the interruptor. I guess it's there to stop all attempts to use the device without any counter-weight to the antenna.

The device cannot show anything absolute of the electromagnetic fields. One can use it as an indicator there's somewhere quite near a radio transmitter just transmitting. Or if he makes adjustmets to a transmitter he can see did they increase or decrease the transmitted electromagnetic field. The potentiometer is needed to attenuate the signal in case the transmitter is very strong or so close that the meter needle jumps to maximum, which prevents any comparisons.

The result depends also heavily and unpredictably on the signal frequency.

Any device which could show something absolute is a complex instrument which is calibrated in a qualified laboratory. This is not one, but it is still useful as a relative indicator of strong signals. Do not expect it does anything useful when the frequency of the signal is higher than 50MHz.

BTW. a low cost radio receiver can detect easily a million times weaker signals than this if both use as effective antenna. None of them measure anything absolute of the detected electromagnetic field except the usual radio receiver can recreate some speech, music or other modulating signals.

Answer (score 0):

The "antenna" is unspecified, which makes your question *"electric field sensing?"* have various answers:

- If the antenna is a complete wire loop returning to the bottom of the 100k potentiometer, then it likely detects **AC magnetic fields** that pass through the loop's area, so long as the length of the loop is a fraction of the wavelength of the AC signal.
- If the antenna is an open-ended wire probe (more likely) then it *almost* detects **AC electric fields**, but not quite, since a ground reference is missing. Its like someone inside an aircraft thinking "we're not going anywhere" until he/she looks out the window.

This circuit might give satisfactory results when the antenna probe is connected to an RF generator - especially if the RF generator's ground is connected to that 100k resistor bottom-end. But RF-coupling from free-space signals via that probe-type antenna is very, very poor.
So it would be a big leap to calibrate it with an RF generator, expecting results out-in-the-field to mean something.

It is a attempt to use two diodes to make a peak-to-peak voltage detector. For signals large enough to overcome the diodes' forward voltage, the DC voltage across the 100k resistor approaches peak-to-peak voltage of an applied AC signal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr3N4x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Diode D1 clamps negative going peaks of V1 at (near) ground, charging C1 with a DC voltage nearly equal to AC peak voltage. This assumes that V1 has a low-impedance to ground - something that a probe antenna lacks, by the way.
On the next half-cycle, the positive peak *adds* to this DC voltage, and makes D2 charge up C2. So C2 sees nearly peak-to-peak voltage. R1 slowly discharges C2, but it is assumed that charging cycles come so quickly that C2 never discharges, at least until V1 stops providing signals.
For example, if V1 is a sine wave having a peak voltage of 10V (its negative peak extends to -10V), then V_out is near 20V with respect to ground.